# Temporary Drop Table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to drop or destroy the database table for a small period of time. Is there any way to drop the table for a temporary situation by MySQL query After that I need to restore it again to use it?

I need my SQL Queries the Drop table temporarily and has to restore it again.

Comment: Use a transaction maybe? Why do you even need this?

Comment: Can you share the context on why you need such functionality? Seems like quite the anti-pattern - if you `DROP` anything you should do so with the expectation that it is generally irreversible.

Comment: Maybe rename the table instead? I too am curious about the use case, though

Comment: I have to do this for some checking security cases. Need to do some panic attacks scenario in the database. after that same tables, I need for other test cases.

Answer (score 1):

you can use mysql binlog flashback your table；
setup 1：
binlog_format=row in your my.cnf

setup2:
show master status;
show binlog events in 'XXXdb-binlog.00000X';

find your action for drop table

setup3:
mysqlbinlog --base64-output=decode-rows -v -v XXXdb-binlog.00000X |sed -n '/### DELETE FROM `db_name`.`table_name`/,/COMMIT/p' > recover_table.txt

setup4：
source recover